# Extension in Remote Environment - vscode.window.showSaveDialog > Open Local File Browser > Response returns relative path which cannot be found

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have an extension with a save feature (exporting data in csv, json, etc) that uses vscode.window.showSaveDialog

In a remote environment, when a user tries to save data and selects a local location through the file browser, then the response uri's path and fsPath that are returned are relative paths/filenames. The response's scheme is "vscode-local"

When a user selects a local location through the dropdown (by clicking through the directories), the response uri's path and fsPath that are returned are absolute paths such as "/mnt/c/Users/../output.json"

I am wondering how to resolve the "vscode-local" file scheme into the absolute directory path, so that I can access and save to this location.

Comment: you want the remote machine access local files, most likely will never happen

Comment: it does in other instances.  the context here is that i am developing an extension for vscode that does and should always work in remote environments.  it does not work in this specific instance.